# Best platform for real time multiplayer 2D cross platform game development

Tags: android, ios, node.js, unity-game-engine, websocket

I have to develop a 2d mulitplayer game (similar to agar.io). I need it for android, IOS and web. There will be rooms with limt of 30 players in a room.
I have done some research and the possible options I have come up to are:
1) Node.js + websockets + html5 (I am condused that whether it will cause lag in my game or not?)
2) Pomelo (http://pomelo.netease.com/)
3) Unity3d + appwarp

Please tell me if any other options. I don't want to spent money on unity license though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use unity3d with photon plugin. I think it's the best solution. You can make 2d games very fast with unity